# Amazonギフト券が有効かのチェックしたい

Tags: amazon

Amazonギフト券を管理画面から商品として登録するシステム作りたいです。

これを、登録時にギフト券の有効のチェックをしたいです。 AmazonのAPIを調査しましたが、それらしい項目はありませんでした。

http://www.ajaxtower.jp/ecs/

AmazonのAPIで、ギフト券の認証は可能でしょうか？

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/22041

Answer (score 1):

Amazonギフト券の転売は利用規約で禁止されていますので、もしAPIがあったとしても質問のような用途で使用することはできないでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
セキュリティの兼ね合いで難しいかと思いっていました。
(ギフト券＝個人情報)

別の方法も検討してみます。